# Как влияет статическая и динамическая линковка на размер приложения?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Как именно влияет статическая и динамическая линковка с `.dll\.lib` на размер приложения?

Comment: ну статическая увеличивает. А проверить не проще?

Comment: @pavel, не проще) Вот к примеру, статическая линкова, статическая длл весит 100 мегабайт, из длл дергается 1 класс и пару статических методов из другого класса. В приложение будет включен весь размер статической длл (+100 мегабайт), либо размер этого класса и пары методов (несколько килобайт), либо вся длл но сжатая?

Comment: Проще проверить, чем предсказать поведение конкретного линкера с конкретными либами и настройками. Qt, например, при статической линковке только добавляет код загрузки DLL, а не код, который из них берет.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, интересует поведение MS VS 2013 (C++)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, и опять же, как проверить? Текущий проект, статическая либа 25 мб, дергается как и написал пару методов и класс. К приложению добавляется 200 килобайт. Но что это? Вся либа сильно сжатая, или только нужные части либы?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, ну и по моему мнению, раз линковщик не стандартизирован, стоит в ответ добавить поведение не одного, а нескольких популярных линковщиков, я думаю это справедливо.

Comment: @Alexis Зависит от конкретных lib. Пример с Qt я привел: статическая линковка не увеличивает и не уменьшает размер приложения ни при каких условиях, код в lib - стабы для дерганья DLL. А за 8,5 лет я не встретил ни одного линкера, который бы сжимал код lib-файлов.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, ну если не сжимает - так выкидывает ненужное (отладочную информацию и т.д.). Конечно лучше бы Вы все это ответом оформили.

Comment: @Alexis да какой ответ-то? Для msvcrt и линкера от MS я знаю поведение. Для Qt определенной версии - знаю. Чего не делают линкеры тоже знаю. А поведение в конкретной ситуации я предсказывать не буду: я соберу и посмотрю на размер.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, я намекал про повышение репутации) За комментарии репутацию не начисляют. Любой труд должен быть оплачен, в данном случае - баллами репутации. Я надеюсь Вы меня поняли.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При ***динамической*** компоновке используются динамические же библиотеки. Они имеют расширение `.dll` и ничем по внутренней структуре не отличаются от исполняемого `.exe`-файла. Когда компоновщик имеет дело с динамической библиотекой, то он **не берёт оттуда никаких кусков кода** (чревато, ибо код машинный), а просто вставляет в компилируемую программу указания типа: «При загрузке программы разместить в указанном месте оперативной памяти адрес функции по имени «XXX» из библиотеки «YYY».

***Статическая*** же библиотека (`.lib`-файл) — это просто архив с объектными файлами внутри. А компоновщику абсолютно без разницы, чьи объектные файлы использовать при компиляции — из родного проекта или из какого-то внешнего источника (необязательно даже статической библиотеки, отдельно лежащий объектный файл тоже сгодится). Если эти файлы особым образом подготовлены, то **включаются только используемые функции** (если особым образом помечены границы функций) или даже **выполняются так называемые межмодульные оптимизации** (если вместо машинного кода использовано высокоуровневое представление). При отсутствии же подобной подготовки будет включено всё содержимое статической библиотеки, даже неиспользуемое.

---

Для тех, кто не понял, о чём речь: компилятор и компоновщик — это две различные, хоть и последовательно работающие, программы. Первая преобразует каждый `.cpp` файлы в полуфабрикатный объектный файл, а вторая собирает объектные файлы в итоговый исполняемый файл.

Answer (score 3):

Компоновка статической библиотеки, в общем случае, даёт больший размер, т.к. в результирующий бинарный файл включатся функции целиком, а при компоновке lib файла dll этого не происходит.

Компонуются в результирующий файл лишь те функции, что компоновщик не может найти в obj файлах — остальные функции не включаются. Это справедливо для обоих случаев.

Comment: `Компоновка статической библиотеки, в общем случае, даёт больший размер` — ...пока не будет скомпилирована с Link-time optimizations (`/LTCG`), что даст компоновщику возможность встраивать функции, предвычислять параметры и удалять мёртвый код.

Comment: @Arhad, это роли не играет, всё равно размер бинарника будет больше при статической линковке, потому что функции нужно куда-то вставлять(а уж если встраивать, так ещё больше будет)

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, имеет ли смысл рассматривать размер программы в отрыве от динамической библиотеки? Ведь если эта библиотека не из какого-то широко используемого фреймворка или API, то её придётся везде «таскать» вместе с основным исполняемым файлом.

Comment: @Arhad, имеет. Одинаковые библиотеки загружаются в память единожды для всех процессов, скомпоновав библиотеку статически, Вы теряете это преимущество. Если это редкая библиотека, тогда, с точки зрения размера, может и не имеет. Но вопрос ведь не в смысле, правда?

Comment: @Arhad, я не совсем верное слово употребил — не «одинаковые», а одни и те же. Это не совсем важно в винде, т.к. это касается только общих библиотек. Это более интересно для линукса, где действительно много библиотек, которые разделяют процессы. В винде всё больше с собой таскают, а не в систему устанавливают, поэтому это преимущество в винде не велико, в общем случае.